# Rendering React.js clientside webapp with PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, phantomjs, server-side-rendering

A friend has asked me to capture a client-side rendered website built with React.js, preferably using PhantomJS. I'm using a simple rendering script as follows:

```
var system = require('system'),
fs = require('fs'),
page = new WebPage(),
url = system.args[1],
output = system.args[2],
result;

page.open(url, function (status) {
if (status !== 'success') {
  console.log('FAILED to load the url');
  phantom.exit();
} else {
  result = page.evaluate(function(){
      var html, doc;

      html = document.querySelector('html');

      return html.outerHTML;
  });

  if(output){

    var rendered = fs.open(output,'w');
    rendered.write(result);
    rendered.flush();
    rendered.close();

  }else{

    console.log(result);

  }
}
phantom.exit();
});
```

The url is http://azertyjobs.tk

I consistently get an error

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Promise

http://azertyjobs.tk/build/bundle.js:34
http://azertyjobs.tk/build/bundle.js:1 in t
...
```

Ok so I figured out that ES6 Promises aren't natively supported by PhantomJS yet, so I tried various extra packages like the following https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise and initiated the variable as such:

```
var Promise = require('es6-promise').Promise
```

However this still produces the same error, although Promise is now a function. The output of the webpage is also still as good as empty (obviously..)

Now I'm pretty oldschool, so this whole client-side rendering stuff is kind of beyond me (in every aspect), but maybe someone has a solution. I've tried using a waiting script too, but that brought absolutely nothing. Am I going about this completely wrong? Is this even possible to do?

Much appreciated!

Ludwig

Comment: PhantomJS has its own terrible Javascript implementation instead of using something sane like Node. If you want to use Phantom with other Node libraries, you have to use terrible integration software like https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node

Comment: @AndyRay has a point. You should probably use Node with something like [Nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare).

Comment: Ok cool guys, will check that out! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the polyfill you linked and it didn't work, changed for [core.js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) and was able to make a screenshot. You need to inject the polyfill before the page is opened:

```
page.onInitialized = function() {
    if(page.injectJs('core.js')){
        console.log("Polyfill loaded");
    }    
}

page.open(url, function (status) {

    setTimeout(function(){
        page.render('output.jpg');
        phantom.exit();
    }, 3000);

});
```

Comment: Ok that sounds promising. Thank you! 

I've installed core.js using `npm i core-js` however (and please excuse my noobiness here) how do I actually access it ?

Comment: Indicate path to core.js file on your computer: `page.injectJs('local/path/to/file/core.js')`. Most simple way is to just move it to directory where the PhantomJS script is.

Comment: Was tired an had overlooked the `/client/` dir of the core-js package. Anyways, this seems to work! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand is that there are several parts of a page loading. First there is the HTML - the same thing you see when you "view source" on a web page. Next there are images and scripts and other resources loaded. Then the scripts are executed, which may or may not result in more content being loaded and possible modifications to the HTML.

What you must do then is figure out a way to determine when the page is actually "loaded" as the user sees it. PhantomJS provides a paradigm for you to [waitFor](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js) content to load. Read through their example and see if you can figure out a method which works for you. Take special note of where they put `phantom.exit();` as you want to make sure that happens at the very end. Good luck.

Comment: Although this is true in many situations, with React apps there are many other issues. For me, it was not including `es2015` in my webpack config so that it didn't compile classes to browser-friendly code properly.

Answer (score 0):

Where (how) are you trying to initialise `Promise`?  You'll need to create it as a property of `window`, or use es6-promise as a global polyfill, like this `require('es6-promise').polyfill();` or this `require('es6-promise/auto');` (from the [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise)).

Also, what do you mean by "capture"? How If you're trying to scrape data, you may have better luck using [X-ray](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray). It supports Phantom, Nightmare and other drivers.

Keep in mind also that React can also be server rendered. React is like templating, but with live data bindings. It's not as complicated as you're making it out to be.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually tried `require('es6-promise').polyfill();` and setting Promise as a property of `window` but neither worked.

Yes I meant scraping the data, thanks for the suggestion, I'll check that out.

I'm aware of that, but that's beyond my control :)